# What does "Vampire Squid of Wall Street" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> But even though Goldman Sachs may be currying favor in Washington, the company not so affectionately known to some as the Vampire Squid of Wall Street may be losing ground to a key rival: Morgan Stanley.

Source: http://money.cnn.com/2017/04/19/investing/morgan-stanley-earnings-wall-street-goldman-sachs/index.html?iid=SF_LN

Comment: It means what it says: the Vampire Squid of Wall Street - a monstrous, all-powerful company that lives at the expense of others.

Comment: Heh, but I'd add that this gives [vampire squids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_squid) a bad name. Even being called "vampire squids" is giving them a bad name as they do not feed on blood and are only so-called because of their "dark colour, cloak-like webbing, and red eyes" (Ibid.).

Comment: It has enveloped the US Congress in a sticky cloud of bioluminescent mucus?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I would bet, although I might be wrong, that CNN was trying to combine two well known terms, and knew nothing about actual vampire squids. Again, I may be underestimating the knowledge base of CNN's reporters.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @StephenS, I would totally agree. But in that case, why rope vampire squids into this :O :D? Now we've sullied the good name of a cephalopod who had just been minding its own business :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Vampire](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vampire): a preternatural being, commonly believed to be a reanimated corpse, that is said to suck the blood of sleeping persons at night.

Basically, vampires are mythical dead people who suck living people's blood to stay "alive."

This is a squid:

[image: squid]

Google Images says [this](http://www.squid-world.com/) is the image source.

Squids have long tentacles, and some similar species (jellyfish) have stingers on them with which they paralyze fish to eat.

There is also a species that was named "vampire squid." See this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_squid).

Basically, Goldman Sachs metaphorically spreads its tentacles to suck everyone else's blood.